# How to insert content from another Custom Post type into Post?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, query-posts, loop, customization

Say I have a custom post type called "Performers". This gets populated with different bands/performers. These posts have a featured image as well as custom fields (mp3 file, facebook link, myspace link, etc).

I have another custom post type called "Events".

When I create a new Event post, I would like the option to have a drop box to select one of the bands from the "Performers" custom post type.

This will insert all data from the specific Band/Performer into the Event post (custom fields, featured image, etc.).

What is the best method for inserting/injecting this sort of loop from the "Event" admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the best way I know to handle that is the [**Posts 2 Posts plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/):

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Here's an example showing how to set up the custom post types *(if you already have them it's more for other's benefit who might be reading this)* as well as the function call to `p2p_register_connection_type()` needed by the plugin to set up the post relationships. This can can go in your theme's `functions.php` file or in a `.PHP` file for a plugin you might be writing:

```
add_action('init','event_performer_init');
function event_performer_init() {
  register_post_type('event',
    array(
      'label'           => 'Events',
      'public'          => true,
      'show_ui'         => true,
      'query_var'       => 'event',
      'rewrite'         => array('slug' => 'events'),
      'hierarchical'    => true,
      //'supports'      => array('title','editor','custom-fields'),
    )
  );
  register_post_type('performer',
    array(
      'label'           => 'Performers',
      'public'          => true,
      'show_ui'         => true,
      'query_var'       => 'performer',
      'rewrite'         => array('slug' => 'performers'),
      'hierarchical'    => true,
      //'supports'      => array('title','editor','custom-fields'),
    )
  );
  if ( function_exists('p2p_register_connection_type') )
    p2p_register_connection_type( 'event', 'performer' );

  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);  // This only needs be done first time
}
```

Then within your theme's template file `single-event.php` you can add code like the following to display information about each Band *(I showed the basics here; I'll leave for you to fill in all the details and/or to ask other more specific questions here on the WordPress Answers site such as if you need to know how to get the featured image, etc.)*

```
<?php
  if (count($performers = p2p_get_connected($post->ID))) {
    foreach($performers as $performer_id) {
      $performer = get_post($performer_id);
      echo 'The Band: ' . apply_filters('the_title',$performer->post_title);
      echo 'Facebook Link: ' . get_post_meta($post->ID,'facebook_link',true);
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, this seems to work pretty well.  2 questions:

-have you played with adjusting the order in which the connected posts are queried?  (I'm assuming they are default by publish date)

-where in the database is this info being stored, is it with the post?  I'm trying to do everything I can without the use of plugins as sometimes they store things into their own created database.

Comment: @Joe: Don't understand _"the order the posts are queried."_ What's the use-case? What you want requires them to store something in the database; no other reasonable *(possible?)* way to do it. Even if you don't use a plugin you'll have to store info in the database. The plugin creates two tables `wp_p2p` and `wp_p2pmeta`. If you want to see a related in-depth _(and heated)_ discussion on this you can read [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14513). Note that scribu championed the use of the taxonomy system for linking but _(without fanfare)_ he switched to using his own linking table.

Comment: Mike:  Sorry for not clarifying- by "order" I mean attaching multiple bands to a single event. :)

Comment: @Joe - Absolutely, that's why I have a loop so that you can loop through the multiple bands that are attached.